# EF: get data with many-to-one relation

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have Entity model generated from DB:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.ProductMeta = new HashSet<ProductMeta>();
    }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int DomainId{ get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductMeta> ProductMeta { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class ProductMeta
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

and want I want to do is get the data from the both tables. What is the best way to join Product with ProductMeta, because ProductMeta have many variants, depends on languageId. Is my where and select are efficent? When I looked into generated SQL, there are many nested SELECT FROM. This is normal?

```
var result = 
            from p in _dbContext.Set<Product >()
            where (p.DomainID == domainId
                && p.IsDeleted == false
                && p.ProductMeta.Select(pm => pm.LanguageID == languageId && pm.IsDeleted == false).FirstOrDefault()
            select(new 
            {
                ProductID = p.ProductID,
                ProductName = p.ProductMeta.FirstOrDefault().ProductName
            });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I recently discovered [this library](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters). Looks like something that could really help you, seeing these recurring predicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try selecting from `ProductMeta`

```
var result = 
    (from pm in _dbContext.Set<ProductMeta>()
    where pm.LanguageID == languageId 
            && pm.IsDeleted == false
            && pm.Product.DomainID == domainId
            && pm.Product.IsDeleted == false
    select pm
    );
```

This will give you an object of type `List<ProductMeta>`.. these objects will have a property call `Product` that will have all of the `Product` properties.  You may need to use `Include` if lazy loading is turned off. That would look like

```
from pm in _dbContext.Set<ProductMeta>().Include("Product")
```

Append `FirstOrDefault()` after the linq query to get just a single `ProductMeta` object

```
select pm).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is only an example. I have many fields in select, both from `Product` and `ProductMeta`, so I must Select from `Product`.

Comment: No you just need to select `ProductMeta` and include `Product`.  I'll update the answer

Comment: if you're trying to build some kind of anonymous type from the select then you just get the product properties using `Field1=pm.Product.Field1` etc

Comment: Are you sure that is a good idea? I have query with join's between 6 tables, which I want to write in EF, so I should use `Include` between every table? For what do I need generated model by EF then, which has the Join between tables?

Comment: You may want to consider using a view if you want to flatten out data from 6 tables, then import the view into your model